# 2つのArrayからHashを作る方法に出てくる*の意味は何でしょうか？

Tags: ruby

[merge two arrays into a hash - Ruby Forum](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/125944)を参考に2つのArrayからHashを作る方法を書きました。

```
keys = %i(a b c)
values = [1,2,3]
Hash[*keys.zip(values).flatten] #=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}
```

この場面に出てくる`*`の意味はなんでしょうか？

```
p *keys
```

とした場合

> :a
>   :b
>   :c

と出力されてしまいますし、RubyMineのブレイクポイントで確認しようとすると、

```
0> *keys
=> /Users/shingo/Documents/sample/hoge.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting '='
(*keys).inspect
```

となってしまいます。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ドキュメントhttp://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.3.0/doc/spec=2fcall.htmlに記述があります。

> 最後の引数の直前に * がついている場合、その引数の値が展開されて渡されます

今回の例では、`keys.zip(values).flatten` の結果の `[:a, 1, :b, 2, :c, 3]` が展開されて、`Hash[:a, 1, :b, 2, :c, 3]` という呼び出しになり、その結果、`{:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}` が得られています。

Answer (score 0):

先の回答で理解できたかと思いますが、*によって引数の値が展開されます。

```
[1] pry(main)> keys = %i(a b c)
=> [:a, :b, :c]
[2] pry(main)> *keys
SyntaxError: unexpected '\n', expecting '='
[2] pry(main)> :a, :b, :c
SyntaxError: unexpected '\n', expecting '='
```

※ `*keys` は `:a, :b, :c` と同じ意味となります。

以上、補足まで。